# CDSA deprecated in OS X Lion. What replaces it?

Tags: cryptography, osx-lion, tokend

I just read that [CDSA is deprecated in OS X 10.7](http://lists.apple.com/archives/fed-talk/2011/Jul/msg00099.html).

What is the recommended replacement?

I am especially interested in the plugin framework: what is the new way to implement access to smartcards etc.? Tokend is deprecated now: what does Mail and Safari use to access private keys?

Comment: Would be very interesting to know indeed. For the time being, Tokend-s (like OpenSC.tokend) will continue to work. But the future is unclear as always with Apple. Meanwhile - enjoy the all natural gestures ;)

Answer (score 1):

As it seems by Apple's own [CommonCrypto](http://www.macintouch.com/specialreports/lion/review4.html#othertech) system.

- Here's a [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/Common%20Crypto.3cc.html) to the man pages.
- It seems to have been originally developed for [iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/Security_Overview/Architecture/Architecture.html).